# What are some decent alt-tab replacements for Gnome?

Tags: gnome, alt-tab

I think these problems bother me with the native alt-tab app:

- It feels a bit sluggish - it takes about 0.3 seconds for the alt-tab window to appear.
- I'd like to configure <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go one window backwards (not sure who to do this with the native one).
- I don't like how the **only** visible window is the window I'm switching too - I'd like a behavior similar to Windows' <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> is controlled by your Window Manager. Gnome uses either metacity or compiz if effects are turned on. They each behave slightly differently with Alt-Tab. I don't have any delay with either WM, Alt-Tab is quite fast on my system.

If you're using Compiz, you try turning down effects in `ccsm` or try switching to Metacity. <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> also works with both WMs. I'm not completely thrilled with Metacity's behavior. When going backwards, it initially skips minimized Windows. Luckily, I rarely find a need to minimize, but it's annoying when I do.

Based on your third point, it sounds like the <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior of Compiz which is just like how Windows 7 ruins <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> if I hold on one Window for too long. That behavior can be configured with `ccsm` under Window Management -> Static Application Switcher -> Appearance -> Selected Window Highlight. Try turning Opacity to 100% and/or changing Highlight Mode.

Your second issue might be a problem with Key Bindings. Key Binding for Compiz are under Window Management -> Static Application Switcher -> Bindings.

Comment: How do I reach ccsm? (Just running ccsm isn't working. Does it mean I'm not using Compiz? How do I find out what I am using?)

Comment: Opacity solves my 3rd problem completely. 1st problem solved by setting "popup window delay" to 0. 2nd point - alt-shift-tab does work, but only if you do it from the start. If you start alt-tabbing, but after a few alt-tabs hold shift, it doesn't start going in reverse (very useful if you pass the target window by just one window) . This is still unsolved, but I'll accept your answer because it's great and solved my other issues - thanks.

Comment: Yes, not having a way to go backwards can get annoying, but I can't seem to reproduce your problem with my Compiz setup. I still suspect it's a binding problem.  My binding for Alt-Tab and Shift-Alt-Tab is Next Window and Prev Window, respectively. I also have bindings for Cntrl-Alt-Tab and Cntrl-Shift-Alt-Tab which are Next Window (All Windows) and  Next Window (All Windows). It sounds like you finally found ccsm.  It was in a separate package on my Ubuntu computer called `compizconfig-settings-manager`. I've also seen the command spelled out on some systems as well.  Hope you get it working!

Comment: @ripper I forgot to mention you in my reply.  I did not notice any difference in behavior between the Control and non Control variation.

Comment: Please write in paragraphs. It's annoying to try and parse or scan a huge wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

If built-in task manager feels sluggish, you can try lightweight standalone alt-tab application: https://github.com/sagb/alttab
Don't forget to disable built-in Alt-Tab key binding as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The Alt-Tab handler is not an "app" and doesn't have "replacements" as in Windows. It is part of the *window manager*.

In GNOME 2 with effects enabled, the WM is Compiz. You can use the [`ccsm`](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) tool to adjust behavior of the "Window Switcher" plugin. (There are two such plugins, by the way.)

Comment: On the contrary, the Alt+Tab handler is an ordinary application under Unix. It can be (and usually is) the same application that does other things such as provide window frames and a task bar.

Comment: @Gilles: Like I said, the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome Shell on Gnome 3.34.3 in Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64, Settings, Devices, Keyboard Shortcuts, Navigation, Switch windows "Alt+Tab" doesn't group, but also doesn't include minimized windows like the [Coverflow Alt-Tab extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) does, which also overrides the normal grouped Switch applications "Super+Tab" [with the same](https://github.com/dmo60/CoverflowAltTab/issues/116).

According to the awful search of Ubuntu Software, "Power Alt-Tab", "Openboxy Alt-Tab", "LinuxLex Alt-Tab Switcher", and especially "Windows Alt Tab" might also work as desired.